# ¿Cómo colocar automáticamente una imagen destacada en una entrada post de wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, web, entrada, wordpress-imagenes

Necesito que en todas mis entradas (post) al inicio del contenido se agregue automáticamente la imagen destacada que puse en ese post, alguna idea de como hacerlo? intenté con the_post_thumbnail( 'medium' ); en el archivo single.php pero me coloca la imagen hasta el tope de mi página y con un fondo horizontal negro. yo necesito colocarlo después de mi titulo de entrada. 
Nota: Uso el tema de Uncode adjunto foto de donde queda al colocarla donde indiqué
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo insertar automaticamente imagen destacada en post (wordpress)?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316055/c%c3%b3mo-insertar-automaticamente-imagen-destacada-en-post-wordpress)

Comment: Por favor no dupliques publicaciones, principalmente cuando la otra fue cerrada, en su lugar te recomiendo seguir los consejos dados y mejorar en lo posible tu pregunta basándote en [ask]

Comment: La otra creo la cerraron sin buenos argumentos, en su opinión no es clara la pregunta?